Movie about three college graduates kidnapped by a nerd they used to bully
I don't know any names, year etc. 
The movie is about 3 college friends that have graduated. They are kidnapped by a nerd that they picked on and bullied in college and he is out for revenge. 
I remember a few scenes like one girl is babysitting for a family member and one room is full of clowns which she hates and I think he gets inside one of the clown costumes then kidnaps her. 
In another scene it's him moving them in a truck to his house and another scene is he has pinned up one of the girls like she is a bug.

Thank thank you Andrew that is the movie!!! I have been trying to remember for months. I love this movie. I know what I'm watching tonight!!!

Tracey, if you ever return, don't forget to click on the checkmark to accept the answer.

It must be Amusement
I have not seen the full film but it did have the clown scene, exactly like you described and there were three girls got kidnapped one by one for an old revenge.
Below is the trailer with that clown scene:- 



